# Is there a way to supress particular messages or a class of messages on the screen?

Tags: 7, debugging

Is there a way of suppressing a particular class of messages from being displayed on the screen, such as the one displayed below?

> Deprecated function: Methods with the same name as their class will
>   not be constructors in a future version of PHP; GeSHi has a deprecated
>   constructor in require_once() (line 837 of
>   {site_root}/sites/all/modules/libraries/libraries.module)

It comes up all the time and it belongs  to the `php` and severity `debug` class of error messages.

I don't want to turn off the display of messages on the screen, just a particular class of message which come so often they are a nuisance.

It is possible to toggle their display on and off when required but still log them to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Disable Messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages) or look how they do it. Among other features you'll get a permission to specifically hide all messages **of a given type** from any role.

> Gives a site owner options to disable specific messages shown to end
>   users. The core drupal message system as offered by drupal_set_message
>   is an excellent way for modules to send out messages to the end users.
>   However not all drupal site owners are keen to show all the messages
>   sent out by drupal core and all modules to their users. This module
>   gives site administrators a reasonably powerful way to filter out
>   messages shown to the end users.
>
> **Features**
>
> - Filter out messages that match a full text string exactly.
> - Filter out messages that match a regular expression.
> - Permissions to specifically hide all messages of a given type from any role.
> - Disable all filtering for specific users.
> - Disable all filtering for specific paths.
> - Apply filtering only for specific paths.
> - Debug system to get messages in the HTML without showing it to the end users.

---

Apart from that I found this little gem:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_status_messages(&$variables) {

  // The exact message you want to filter.
  $message = 'Further instructions have been sent to your e-mail address.';

  if (isset($_SESSION['messages'])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION['messages'] as $type => $messages) {

      // Limit it to a certain type if you want to.
      if ($type == 'status') {

        $pos = array_search($message, $messages);

        if ($pos !== FALSE) {
          unset($_SESSION['messages'][$type][$pos]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Source: https://api.drupal.org/comment/51793#comment-51793

---

Here's another alternative to filter all messages of a certain type.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_build().
 */
function MYMODULE_page_build(&$page) {

  $hide_types = ['status', 'error', 'warning'];

  if (isset($_SESSION['messages'])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION['messages'] as $type => $messages) {
      if (in_array($type, $hide_types)) {
        unset($_SESSION['messages'][$type]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could also easily get the `$account = global $user` and check its roles to tighten this request if you need.

---

Last but not least – **not recommended** - you can remove or if-wrap the `<?php print $messages; ?>` variable in your theme's `page.tpl.php`. But editing templates for this kind of logic should be considered bad practice.

Comment: I have this module on my system, but it seems to be applied to end users only,but not for the administrator, which is what I am really looking for.

Comment: @vfclists – Permissions are set role-wise. Isn't this sufficient?

Comment: I will look into that

Comment: @vfclists – Added some snippets to be used in a custom module. Placing them into your theme's `template.php` might work as well.